# Different Column number for each rows in GridView android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have to create UI using the Gridview. The image are dynamic since it is coming from the webservice .

I can define column number using the xml but the item at the zeroth index has to have one full image and then the rest should be divided into columns .

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using ListView .Added a view to listView Header. Then inside the child for the list view I added two view .In the getView method of the custom adapter I incremented the position by one everytime.

P.S: If you want to implement the above view using endless adapter you will have to find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use a [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). `GridView` does not support spanning operations.

> A layout that arranges its children into rows and columns. A
>   TableLayout consists of a number of TableRow objects, each defining a
>   row (actually, you can have other children, which will be explained
>   below). TableLayout containers do not display border lines for their
>   rows, columns, or cells. Each row has zero or more cells; each cell
>   can hold one View object. The table has as many columns as the row
>   with the most cells. A table can leave cells empty. **Cells can span
>   columns**, as they can in HTML.

You can see an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/).

Comment: Thats true but i need i have dynamic data that is coming so even if i draw the view each time will not solve the problem instead create a new problem altogether for me.I guess i'll landup facing outofmemory issue

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jack K Fouani. Some changes that will save entire image from cropping:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <!-- Large Image   -->
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    <!-- //Large Image -->

    <!-- Small Images -->
    <GridView 
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:numColumns="auto_fit"
      android:columnWidth="120dip"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="0dip" >
   </GridView>
    <!-- Small Images -->

</LinearLayout>
```

A fast solution, others have a lot of work, try it. you may like it.

```
GridView gv = findViewById(R.id.list);
        gv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int firstVisibleItem, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ImageView iView = findViewById(R.id.image);
                if (firstVisibleItem == 0)
                {
                    iView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    iView.setVisibility(View.Gone);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I guess i have already thought about this but this is not the solution .Because when i'll try to scroll only the grid will scroll but i need the whole view to scroll along

Comment: you didn't mention this in your question anyway. provide your xml layout.

Comment: Sorry my bad .I have landed up figuring it out. What u have pasted above is the same i have done till now.

Comment: @Terril I am trying to do the same thing. What solution did you use? Thanks

Comment: @JessicaM: I used a listview and moified my adapter as per my requirement. Just added a list header and added an ImageView .

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GrideView` weight=1 and above of it add `ImageView`

for example if you want to use `GrideView` this is full example Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <!-- Large Image   -->
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <!-- //Large Image -->

    <!-- Small Images -->
    <GridView 
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:numColumns="auto_fit"
      android:columnWidth="120dip"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="0dip" >
   </GridView>
    <!-- Small Images -->

</LinearLayout>
```

this layout will be exactly the same of your request

[image]

Comment: I guess i have already thought about this but this is not the solution .Because when i'll try to scroll on the grid will scroll but i need the whole view to scroll along

Comment: then you need to change w/h of first element inside GrideView , you can call `Display` to get current w/h of user device then set width=display.w and height= 50% of display height

Comment: Even if i do that how can i then handle the rest of the Views .I guess u mean to say using Display metric i can get the Width of the each device then for position at zero i'll add it to gridview.But what about the number column that i have already added.

Comment: use static h/w for the rest of columns but for position=0 use costume h/w just like u said

Comment: thats not possible @Jack